Using Custom Converters in SelectWhereStep
What is the recommended way of using custom converters in the SelectWhereStep of a query?
I have the following database table:
product
- id INT
- name VARCHAR
- type VARCHAR

Values in the product table look something like



id
name
type




1
Generic Book
paperback_book


2
Today's News
digital_newspaper


3
Hot Magazine
paper_magazine



The important part is the type column, which is a denormalized VARCHAR in the database. It is a concatenated value of a type of book and the medium.
I have a class in Java called ProductType which represents this:
public class ProductMediumType {
    private ProductType type; // This is an enum
    private Medium medium; // This is an enum
    .....
}

I've created an implementation of org.jooq.Converter as defined here: Custom data type conversion
public class ProductMediumTypeConverter extends AbstractConverter<String, ProductMediumType> {}

I want to use this in the SelectWhereStep:
ProductMediumTypeConverter mediumTypeConverter = .....;
ProductMediumType mediumType = ....;


Product prod = create
    .select(
        PRODUCT.ID, 
        PRODUCT.NAME,
        PRODUCT.TYPE.convert(mediumTypeConverter)
    )
    .from(PRODUCT)
    .where(PRODUCT.TYPE.eq(/* HERE */))
    .fetchInto(Product.class);

I know I can use the .to() method of the converter directly, but I don't think that reads well. Is there a better way of doing this?
Also, I know I can create custom converters and use them during code generation, but unfortunately that is not feasible in my case.

I'm assuming you're using jOOQ's code generator, in case of which you can simply attach your converter to your generated code, and now you don't have to do anything anymore. jOOQ will always automatically convert between the database type (e.g. String) and your user type (e.g. ProductMediumType):
// You'll get the right type in your result sets:
Result<Record3<Integer, String, ProductMediumType>> result =
Product prod = create
    .select(
        PRODUCT.ID, 
        PRODUCT.NAME,
        PRODUCT.TYPE                    // Nothing needed here
    )
    .from(PRODUCT)
    .where(PRODUCT.TYPE.eq(mediumType)) // Nothing needed here either
    .fetch();

If you're not using the code generator, or cannot attach the converter to your generated code for any other reason, just attach the converter to your PRODUCT.TYPE field, and reuse that instead:
Field<ProductMediumType> convertedType = 
    PRODUCT.TYPE.convert(mediumTypeConverter);

// Now, use it everywhere:
Product prod = create
    .select(
        PRODUCT.ID, 
        PRODUCT.NAME,
        convertedType
    )
    .from(PRODUCT)
    .where(convertedType.eq(mediumType))
    .fetchInto(Product.class);


Perfect! Thank you. I would love to attach the converter to the code generator, but this database is from an ERP with essentially no normalization and no consistency in column naming. It's probably still worth exploring though. Appreciate all the help!

@Conner: It's still worth it, even if there is no consistent naming schema. You can use regular expressions to match all qualified column names for which a converter applies. You'll do the work only once, and then every query will profit from it!
